# Sort table based on the # of img tags in a given element

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table

```
<body>

    <table id="myTable">
        <caption>
          SF6 LeaderBoard
        </caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Character Icon</th>
            <th scope="col">Username</th>
            <th scope="col">Badges</th>
            <th scope="col">Faction</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"></th>
            <td>fighter2</td>
            <td><img style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;" src ="https://i.ibb.co/NSwLYkR/MARISSA-EMBLEM.png" height="50" ></td>
            <td>Blitz</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><img src="https://www.fightersgeneration.com/nx9/char/ultra-sf4-chibi/chunli-ultra-sf4-chibi.png" height="100" width="100"></th>
            <td>fighter1</td>
            <td><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"> <img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"></td>
            <td>Galaxy</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <th scope="row"><img src="https://www.fightersgeneration.com/nx9/char/ultra-sf4-chibi/chunli-ultra-sf4-chibi.png" height="100" width="100"></th>
            <td>KaiRosFGC</td>
            <td><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"> <img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"></td>
            <td>Galaxy</td>
          </tr>
   
      
         
        </tbody>
        
      </table>
   

<script>
    function sortTable() {
   var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
   table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   switching = true;
   while (switching) {
     switching = false;
     rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
       shouldSwitch = false;
       x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].getElementsByTagName("img").length;
       console.log(x);
       y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].getElementsByTagName("img").length;
       if (x < y) {
         shouldSwitch = true;
         break;
       }
     }
     if (shouldSwitch) {
       rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
       switching = true;
     }
   }
 }
 console.log('hello');
       </script>
```

Hi im trying to create a sorting method that takes the number of img tags in a tr element and changes the order if the element has less img tags than the next. but when i run this code nothing happens at all. I have tried to move the script tags because maybe the location was the issue but i still run into the same problem of nothing being reordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a lot easier using a standard array-sort for tackling the problem:

```js
function sortTable(tblsel){
 const tbd=document.querySelector(tblsel).querySelector("tbody"),
   trs=[...tbd.querySelectorAll("tr")];
 trs.forEach(tr=>tr.count=tr.querySelectorAll("img").length);
 // the following sorts in ascending order, swap a and b for descending order:
 trs.sort((a,b)=>a.count-b.count).forEach(tr=>tbd.append(tr));
}
sortTable("table");
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border=1>
    <caption>
      SF6 LeaderBoard
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Character Icon</th>
        <th scope="col">Username</th>
        <th scope="col">Badges</th>
        <th scope="col">Faction</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td>fighter2</td>
        <td><img style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;" src ="https://i.ibb.co/NSwLYkR/MARISSA-EMBLEM.png" height="50" ></td>
        <td>Blitz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><img src="https://www.fightersgeneration.com/nx9/char/ultra-sf4-chibi/chunli-ultra-sf4-chibi.png" height="100" width="100"></th>
        <td>fighter1</td>
        <td><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"> <img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"></td>
        <td>Galaxy</td>
      </tr> <tr>
        <th scope="row"><img src="https://www.fightersgeneration.com/nx9/char/ultra-sf4-chibi/chunli-ultra-sf4-chibi.png" height="100" width="100"></th>
        <td>KaiRosFGC</td>
        <td><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"><img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"> <img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/31-313648_boulder-badge-rock-gym-badge-pokemon-clipart.png" height="40" width="40"></td>
        <td>Galaxy</td>
      </tr>        
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: that makes more sense im transfering over from java to javascript and some of the approaches im not fully aware of thank you for the help i was able to use this.